# selecting records from main table and count of each row in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 table in my database that tables are in relationship with foreign key 
I want to select all records from main table and then select count of each row in another table than have same ID from main table I tried to create a select query but it is not work correctly
this query return all records from main table + count of all records from next table(not count of each row in relationship)

```
    SELECT tblForumSubGroups_1.id, tblForumSubGroups_1.GroupID,
    tblForumSubGroups_1.SubGroupTitle, tblForumSubGroups_1.SubGroupDesc,
    (SELECT COUNT(dbo.tblForumPosts.id) AS Expr1
    FROM dbo.tblForumSubGroups INNER JOIN dbo.tblForumPosts ON 
    dbo.tblForumSubGroups.id = dbo.tblForumPosts.SubGroupID) AS Expr1
    FROM dbo.tblForumSubGroups AS tblForumSubGroups_1 INNER JOIN
    dbo.tblForumPosts AS tblForumPosts_1 ON tblForumSubGroups_1.id 
    = tblForumPosts_1.SubGroupID
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: There's no need to join tblForumPosts since it's in the sub-query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  tblForumSubGroups_1.id, tblForumSubGroups_1.GroupID, tblForumSubGroups_1.SubGroupTitle, tblForumSubGroups_1.SubGroupDesc,
        COUNT(tblForumPosts_1.id) AS Expr1
FROM    dbo.tblForumSubGroups AS tblForumSubGroups_1
INNER JOIN  dbo.tblForumPosts AS tblForumPosts_1 ON tblForumSubGroups_1.id = tblForumPosts_1.SubGroupID
GROUP BY tblForumSubGroups_1.id, tblForumSubGroups_1.GroupID, tblForumSubGroups_1.SubGroupTitle, tblForumSubGroups_1.SubGroupDesc
```

Comment: Just a comment, if you change to LEFT JOIN, forums with zero postings will be listed!

Comment: hi mr.gajjar ty for reply its worked , now i want to ask you a question , i have three table in database last table is "tblForumReplyPost" and i want to get count of replys for each row how i must add it in my query? that table in relationship with "tblForumPosts" with ID and tblForumReplyPost with PostID

Comment: join the table - tblForumReplyPost in the same query, and add COUNT(tblForumReplyPost.ID) AS Expr2 to SELECT list. As pointed out by @jarlh use LEFT JOIN if you need include forums with 0 postings or replies. There will be no changes to GROUP BY clause.

Comment: ty useful help , have you any yahoo, skype , viber id? i will be in relationship with you , it is big honor for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix sub-query and join logic. Use only one of them. I prefer sub-select.

```
SELECT tblForumSubGroups_1.id,
       tblForumSubGroups_1.GroupID,
       tblForumSubGroups_1.SubGroupTitle,
       tblForumSubGroups_1.SubGroupDesc,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM dbo.tblForumPosts
        WHERE dbo.tblForumSubGroups.id = dbo.tblForumPosts.SubGroupID) AS Expr1
FROM dbo.tblForumSubGroups AS tblForumSubGroups_1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest cross apply as you can do a lot more things with it ...

```
SELECT t1.id,
   t1.GroupID,
   t1.SubGroupTitle,
   t1.SubGroupDesc,
   t2.val
FROM dbo.tblForumSubGroups AS t1
cross apply (SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM dbo.tblForumPosts as t2
         WHERE t1.id = t2.SubGroupID) x(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to supply another answer though I believe the cross apply is likely the best option:

```
SELECT 
    A.id, A.GroupID, A.SubGroupTitle, A.SubGroupDesc,
    B.IDCount AS Expr1
FROM dbo.tblForumSubGroups A 
INNER JOIN (
    Select SubGroupID, Count(ID) as IDCount
    from dbo.tblForumPosts
    Group By SubGroupID
) B On A.ID = B.SubGroupID
```